# When does "t-y" become a "ch" and "d-y" does a "dj"?

Tags: phonology, fast-speech-rules, palatalization

- 'That you' becomes 'Thach you'
- 'Did you' becomes 'Dij you' (or something near this)
  But body, responsibility doesn't. When that happens?

Comment: When? When speaking English. The process is called [palatalization](https://www.google.com/search?q=palatalization) and it produces a /tʃ/ from a /t/ when preceding an /i/ or /y/ at normal speech rates. This applies to the **sounds** of English, not the spellings. _Body_ is pronounced /'badi/, with a stressed vowel, not a /y/.

Comment: This is quite like what happens in most Brazilian Portuguese to the ends of words like *frente* and *facilidade* (but not in European Portuguese, Galician, Spanish, etc). It's also why C becomes S not K before E/I, and why words like *action, rational, session,,vision, concious, conscience, measure, erasure, tonsure, discussion, fusion, tissue, species, sugar, sure* and many thousands more all get palatalized. In all these cases you have to place the blame on the "yod" /j/ sound. See also Iberian words from Latin *pl/cl-* that all palatalized into *ch/ll-* there, unlike in French or Italian.